# Visual Studio Code HTML Colors are off?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can anyone help me figure out why code colors seems to be off? Doesnt matter what theme I am using, my element tags are always the same color as the text that might be in it.

I tried a reinstall and that didnt change anything.

Thank you

[example of my issue (in the nav)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uaqd5.jpg)

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio, or Visual Studio Code? It looks like Code, check this link out and see if it helps:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the cause is but I fixed it by following the instructions on this page. Seems to have normalized everything by doing a complete reinstall

[Complete uninstall of vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac)