# How to uninstall VS Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, uninstallation

I used following command from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac). but it didn't remove VS Code from my mac. I still see `.config` file associated with `vscode` logo and when i click on it, it opens vs code application.

```
rm -fr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.helper.plist 
rm -fr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist 
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/
rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/
rm -fr ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState/
rm -fr ~/.vscode/
```

I have same issue with `atom` as well. How can I uninstall these apps :(

Comment: I have already done that but it didn't help. This was one of the step mentioned in the original stackoverflow question that i linked in my post.

Comment: I am also having this issue. It must also be also be somewhere else, not sure where though.

Answer (score -3):

Go to Path:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code

Double Click

> uninstall.exe

It will uninstall vs code from your Windows Computer.