# Python3 not accepting my keyboard input after clicking enter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkMG5.png)

This randomly happened where my keyboard inputs are not being accpeted once i click enter. From the picture you can see i typed in 10 at first then i clicked enter and ntohing happened to where i can keep continuiosly typing so i typed a 5 after. Once i stop debugging i get the error showing none of the inputs were accepted. I uninstalled all my extensions and even vscode but no luck.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Your question must be self-contained: no off-site links.  Include the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: it seems problem with VS Code and you should write it to VS's authors

Comment: This is my first time using this. Sorry. I just really need help with this if anyone knows the issue thats causing this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this issue and i posted the bug issue on github so they can hopefully fix it on the next update.

The issue was in the latest version of the python interpreter extension (2020.8.101144) and luckily downgrading it to the one below it works fine.