# VSCode cannot read user input while debugging a python code in integratedTerminal

Tags: python, debugging, input, visual-studio-code

In this two-line python code:

```
string = input("What's your name? ")

if string != '': print('Hello, ' + string + '!')
```

While I run debugging, it waits for user input. After typing a name, the Terminal (Python Debug Console) just halts there, the print() line never gets executed.
[See the screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVVUR.png)

The launch.json file is below (as default):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run this code without debugging, everything is OK.

NOTE: The debugger works fine before. This problem just happened recently.
Very much appreciate any helps or hints.

Comment: Try removing the breakpoint

Comment: @eggheadlabs Since the debug function is provided by the python extension, you could try to disable other extensions and install the python extension again(or use other versions of python extensions.). refer to: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1125

Comment: @JillCheng Thanks for your suggestion. I've rolled the python extension back to its previous version (v2020.7.96456), then the problem is gone and everything is OK. It seems to me a bug was introduced in the latest version (v2020.8.101144). I also tried to uninstall and reinstall the latest version but the problem was still persisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I rolled back the python extension to its previous version (v2020.7.96456), then the problem is gone and the debugger can advance to next line of code and then works properly.

Though I have no hard prove that why does the latest version (v2020.8.101144) cause the debugger stoping accepting user input, at least rolling back to a previous version can be a temporary remedy, until future revisions address this issue.

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with this all day. As soon as I rolled back the Python extension this was resolved.

Comment: UPDATE: VSCode has fixed this terminal input issue in v2020.8.1 (20 Aug 2020) version for the Python extension.