# Flutter auto importing extension file is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, import, extension-methods

I have a simple `String-Extension` which looks like this:

```
extension TranslationHelper on String {
  String localized() {
    return AppLocalizations(Locale('de', 'DE')).translate(this);
  }
}
```

With this I am able to call `.localized()` on any `String`.

**Problem:** Flutter or VSCode is not auto-importing the file for me and also not suggesting it with a *Quick-Fix*. Importing the file manually is quite painful. Is this a bug or what am I missing here?

All other importing works perfectly fine...

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue, and is being [tracked](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38894).

As a workaround, typing the name of the extension should let you auto import it.
For example, with the following extension, typing `MyExtension` should allow you to import it.

```dart
extension MyExtension on Object {
  void doSomething() {}
}
```