# XCode and VSCode Issues

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, installation

Last year (early 2020), I downloaded an earlier form of XCode onto my 2011 MacBook. It worked great, but around June 2020, I must have deleted something during a file cleanout. Any attempt to download any version of XCode leads to my terminal claiming I already have it installed, yet opening XCode is impossible. I downloaded Visual Studio Code in an attempt to replace it, but my terminal cannot connect with it, making it impossible to run properly. All my software is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you reinstall XCode and review compatibility because the last official update for a 2011 MacBook is High Sierra, then you can only use Xcode 10.

For Visual Studio Code, you also try to uninstall and then download an appropriate version.

[Unistall Xcode](https://inthetechpit.com/2019/12/31/how-to-clean-uninstall-xcode-on-mac/)

[Xcode releases](https://developer.apple.com/download/more)

[Unistall Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac)

[VSCode releases](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, redownloading any sort of XCode does not work. I want to reconfigure my terminal to run with VSCode