# How to do a complete uninstall of Visual Studio Code on a Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I seem to be making things worse with trying to fix the terminal configuration...I think it would be easier to just start from scratch. Does anyone have some easy to follow steps on how to completely uninstall VS Code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely uninstall vscode on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code), you should delete `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code` and `~/.vscode` after uninstalling the software to completely remove  user data.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try