# Visual Studio Code extensions stopped working suddenly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm having problem with my Visual Studio Code. Yesterday I had my pc shut down with VS Code open, and when I turned pc on again, all VS Code extensions stopped working. I'm using React and Typescript in my project and I really need those extensions. My eslint and prettier configurations also stopped working.
If somebody had the same problem please answer.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had this problem too. You can fix with the following:

1. Open the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Run `Disable All Installed Extensions`
3. Then run `Enable All Extensions`.
4. Restart Visual Studio Code

You can make sure again that the extensions are enabled.

Comment: I can't believe it works, ‍♂️, I was already installing vim again and cursing Microsoft for their lame editor, lol.

Comment: @WernerEchezuria You have 100% right ! It works perfectly well ;-) !

Comment: I also have this problem. Your fix unfortunately does not work for me. Next to the extension in command pallette, a message says 'restart server'.  Not sure how to solve this..

Comment: I suddenly got the error `Error: there is no registered task type 'typescript'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?` and got it fixed with this answer too.

Answer (score 6):

i too had a similar issue, and found (thru trial and error and multiple stackoverflow searches)

#### fix

- toggle Developer Tools once you have vs code open
- select the `console` tab
- scroll thru the log, paying close attention to the red errors/
  - if it's extension errors, open file explorer and go
  `$drive:\Users\Yourname.vscode\extensions`
- delete any problem extensions
- Restart VSCode and all should be well (at least for me it was)

### cheers and happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). The error was like this:

```
/mnt/c/Users/Admin/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.63.13/scripts/wslCode.sh: 69: /home/raul/.vscode-server-server/bin/5554b12acf27056905806867f251c859323ff7e9/bin/code: not found
```

---

The solution was to go to Windows PowerShell and open Visual Studio Code, then go to the extensions and restart the *Remote - WSL* extension, and go back to WSL. It then started working immediately.

Answer (score 2):

in my case removing "Todo Tree" plugin which is one of the VS Code plugins solved the problem,

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.todo-tree

if it is installed uninstall it and the problem will be solved

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33111790)

Answer (score 0):

It's weird. when I use WSL2 terminal opening Visual Studio Code, an exception occurs, expressing that `wslCode.sh: 69`.

But when I open Visual Studio Code in Windows, then type `code .` in WSL2 terminal, it works without an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are able to turn on your settings sync. I had an issue like this and I couldn't even access the account option on vs code (the second last icon on the right horizontal panel.

If not (it's a long shot) try uninstalling vs code and reinstalling VS Code completely. I used [these commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47561948/9212849) to do so (works for mac)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in the portable version (1.73.3). I deleted the extensions folder `{vscode root}/data/extensions`. Re-installing all extensions afterwards worked for me