# VS Code and Terminal differ in Python Locations

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I recently uninstalled and re-installed VS Code due to wanting a fresh start. However, now VS Code says python3 is under Library/Frameworks... and python is under `/usr/bin/python`. In the terminal these are both `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python3` for `which python` and `which python3`. Why the difference?

To uninstall VS Code (on a mac) I first deleted the application and removed it from trash. Then I followed the set of commands [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac). Then re-installed it like normal.

Answer (score 0):

If local environment changes, restart vscode is needed to make change effective in it. So check if it's not restarting vscode that causes different result in integrated and external terminal.

About resetting VS Code, you can delete `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code` and `~/.vscode`. View [How can I do a 'clean' uninstall of VS Code?](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code)

Try and see if it helps solve your question.

Comment: I already did a clean restart of VS code. Are you proposing to check again and if the differences still exist then do another clean restart?

Comment: @JackArmstrong. Yes, I believe it's not resetting vscode completely that caused this difference. so please reset again.