# MacOS: VSCode C/C++ intellisense fails to deduce types

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, intellisense

MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, VSCode 1.64.2 (Universal) :I had the intellisense working for my project without problems, but then for whatever reason it has stopped working in some cases:
whenever I assign something to an 'auto variable', for example: `auto val = (float)foo;` I'd get intellisense error: `int val: explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)C/C++(260)`.
Class enums are not recognised as they should, so I can't use `EnumClass::Enum` or get any enum-related autocomplete support.
Those are the most reoccuring problems, but I'd say the intellisense generally doesn't work properly.
I removed everything related to VSCode (using this: [How to completely uninstall vscode on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac)) and reinstalled with just C/C++ extention enabled and the problem persists. I have other people using the same setup with this project and they don't have this problem. I tried older versions of the extention without success aswell.
Is there anything I could try to get it back to work?

Comment: Have you set `"cppStandard": "c++11"` or newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that intellisense is using older c++ version for determining the syntax.
The way to fix this is to set to some newer version like c++17

Go to settings in your VSCode and search for `Cpp Standard` and from the dropdown select `c++17` or any newer version that you use.

In case you follow JSON style settings, then search for following
`"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17"`

Attaching the screenshot of the settings page
[image: UI based setting screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! This solves the problem. My projest it c++11 based, so I set it to c++11 and it now works.