# VS Code Git: spawn EBADF

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My VS code started to be super-slow with git and I am often seeing error with EBADF, either when searching files or working with git.

I saw that disk might not be available. I have Mac Pro 2020. Is this a hardware issue or could it be fixed?

Comment: On macOS, use the Apple menu "About This Mac" and click on "System report", check Console and other logging facilities, and/or use Disk Utility to check the health of the hardware. (But EBADF issues are usually software bugs; you'd be seeing EIO errors for real hardware problems.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved: I completely uninstalled VS code (including cache files etc) and install it again. No more such errors and it's much faster now.

Comment: Good catch. Not sure why the original installation was buggy that way.

Comment: For reference, here is how to uninstall VS Code completely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vs-code-on-mac

Answer (score 0):

First, switch back to command line, and make sure you can add, commit and push your work in progress.

That way, you can explore the root cause without risking losing anything.

Ideally, try and clone again the repository to a local drive, open VSCode from that new local folder, and see if you still get EBADF ("error bad file descriptor") issues.

Comment: didn't help and it's still there.. any other suggestion?)

Comment: @Petr Do you mean you still see those errors in command line only? If yes, what is your git version?

Comment: I solved it now by uninstalling VS Code (including cache) and installing again. Thanks for your help tho :)